# Why does blazor render twice?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am working on a basic blazor webassembly project. Everything was going perfectly until I came across this situation. Project works but renders twice.

Project is about Pagination, Quickly, I want to show you my classes related to it.

ThList.razor:

```
@foreach (var item in List)
{
    <Th @bind-Name="item.Name" @bind-Class="item.Class" @bind-IsCurrent="item.IsCurrent" OnClick="OnClick"></Th>
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public IList<Th> List { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IList<Th>> ListChanged { get; set; }

    public void OnClick(Th th)
    {
        foreach (var item in List)
        {
            item.IsCurrent = item.Name == th.Name;
            item.SetClass();
            (item.Name + " " + item.IsCurrent).ToConsole();
        }
    }
}
```

Th.razor:

```
<th @attributes="InputAttributes" class="@Class" @onclick="(()=>OnClick.InvokeAsync(this))">@Name</th>

@code{
    private readonly string _defaultClass = "sorting";

    private bool _IsCurrent;

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsCurrent
    {
        get { return _IsCurrent; }
        set
        {
            _IsCurrent = value;
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> IsCurrentChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ClassChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Th> OnClick { get; set; }

    public void SetClass()
    {
        if (IsCurrent) $"{Name}: here is setclass".ToConsole();
        if(IsCurrent)
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Class))
                Class = $"{_defaultClass}_asc";
            else
                Class = Class.Contains("asc") ? Class.Replace("asc", "desc") : Class.Replace("desc", "asc");
        else
            Class = _defaultClass;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> InputAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "tabindex", "0" },
        { "rowspan", "1" },
        { "colspan", "1" },
        { "style", "width: 14px;"}
    };
}
```

DataTables.razor:

```
***
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <ThList @bind-List="ThList"></ThList>
            </tr>
        </thead>
***
@code {
    IList<Th> ThList = new List<Th>()
    {
        new Th(){Name = "Id", IsCurrent = true},
        new Th(){Name = "Name"},
        new Th(){Name = "Surname"},
        new Th(){Name = "Email"},
        new Th(){Name = "Gender"}
    };

    IList<PaginateButton> paginateButtonList = new List<PaginateButton>()
    {
        new PaginateButton(){Name = "1", IsCurrent = true},
        new PaginateButton(){Name = "2"},
        new PaginateButton(){Name = "3"}
    };

    DataTablesRequest dataTablesRequestModel = new DataTablesRequest();
}
```

Note: I read [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but I couldn't understood exactly. I'm new to Blazor. Please someone explain to me and show me a way.

Comment: I can't explain better than the docs, except to say, put simply, async calls are still running after the page has rendered and when it completes, there is another rendering to update what the async task has changed.

Comment: Thanks, I know async calls but I didn't use any async method. This is the point I don't understand

Comment: It is being done as part of the framework, for instance SetParametersAsync

Comment: I think I'm very close to the solution thanks to you (with OnParametersSetAsync method)